# Keybindings for Quarto in VSCode not working "command not found"

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, quarto

I have the Quarto extension installed in VSCode. None of the default keyboard shortcuts for Quarto work. For example pressing ctrl+enter will not run my current line, and vscode gives message "Command 'quarto.runCurrent' not found. The keybindings are present in my json file.  Similar keybindings/keyboard shortcuts all work for .rmd files, but not .qmd. I would like to use Quarto, please help.

I have tried re-installing Quarto extension.